# Do downvotes/flags still affect the original owner of a community wiki post other than for rep calculation?

Tags: support, community-wiki, post-ban

Some time ago I was pointed to a ranting/rude answer that was immediately converted to wiki by the poster. Since at the time it seemed pretty clear that the poster originally posted the rant and then as soon the situation turned bad converted it to a wiki post to avoid the downvote rain, I was left wondering on the full implications of this apparent attempt to game the system.

As most will know, the fact that the post was converted to wiki means that in its (hopefully short) life the post is there, getting  more downvotes but the poster does no longer get any **visible** effect out of it: any vote casted after the conversion has no **visible** effect on the poster reputation

This brings then to my question: does the flagging/deletion/voting system still maintain all the other side effects outside of rep calculation? For example, does flagging the now-wiki post contribute to question/answer ban for the original owner?

I was thinking of a scenario like the following:

> Bob, already on the verge of ban, posts another rude/bad answer. The downvotes start to rain as he realizes that his rep is dropping faster than the world has ever known. He deletes the answer hoping to save himself, but that in return triggers the answer ban. What happens if Bob now converts the answer to wiki, and what would have happened if he converted it **before** the deletion?

Can anyone provide some insight? I have tried looking at the FAQs for community-wiki questions, but this specific aspect is not covered (maybe intentionally). I would assume that only the rep is lost but other side effects are kept  (including the "You are banned" one)... but you can never be sure.